# Unable to convert MySQL.DateTime to System.DateTime with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 values

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am working on a C# project and I am facing an issue. The program allows the user to connect to a MySQL database and retrieve information from each selected table and write the data out to a file. The problem is because I have no idea what the schema is going to be like or what values its going to contain.

If the timestamp column contains the date 0000-00-00 00:00:00 I get the conversion error and no matter what I try it never works. I've tried converting to a string I've tried converting to a DateTime but I always get the error.

Below is how I am currently trying to get the data:

```
using (ConnectMySQLDB db = new ConnectMySQLDB(databaseSettings))
{
   string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}.{1}", database, table);
   Console.WriteLine("Query: {0}", query);
   using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.conn))
   {
      using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
         int i = 1;
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", i);
            fieldsAndValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (ColumnDataTypes fieldAndType in fieldsAndTypes)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Column: {0} Type: {1}", fieldAndType.field, fieldAndType.dataType);
               string formattedValue = "";
               if (fieldAndType.dataType == "timestamp")
               {
                  DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(reader.GetDateTime(fieldAndType.field).ToString());
                  formattedValue = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
               }

               else
               {
                  formattedValue = getDBFormattedValue(reader.GetString(fieldAndType.field), fieldAndType.dataType);
                  fieldsAndValues.Add(fieldAndType.field, formattedValue);
               }
            }
            rows.Add(fieldsAndValues);
            i++;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also have added the allow zero date and convertzerodate to null option in the connector string as follows:

```
connString = "server=" + server + ";uid=" + username + ";pwd=" + password + ";port=" + port + ";Allow Zero Datetime=true;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull;Convert Zero Datetime=true";
```

Comment: Why are you converting a DateTime to a string and then parsing it back again? Surely you would only ever want it to return the same DateTime it started with.

Comment: Also, you haven't told us what actually happens. You say you get "the error" but without saying what that error is.

Comment: Which MySQL connector are you using, by the way? Everything I've seen about those connection string options suggests it's for a Java driver. Are you sure the driver you're using supports them?

Comment: @JonSkeet the error is in the title. I want the date to be end up in a string but I read somewhere that you need to convert to a .net datetime and then convert back to a string

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not 100% sure whether they should work or not, from what I read they mentioned C# but I could be wrong. I'm using the ado.net connector from mysql

Comment: Ah - it wasn't at *all* clear that that was the error; it sounded like your description of the title. And no, you definitely shouldn't convert a DateTime to a string and then back. Just using `reader.GetDateTime` is how you should get a DateTime.

Comment: I've tried ``DateTime date = reader.getDateTime(field);`` and its still not working, get the same error

Comment: Have you done that *after* changing to just specify ConvertZeroDateTime=true though, as I've suggested?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks this has worked, I took out the wrong thing from the connector string. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html), it looks like you're specifying two contradictory options (`AllowZeroDateTime=true` and `ConvertZeroDateTime=true`) and one which appears not to be listed (`ZeroDateTimeBehavior=ConvertToNull`).

I suggest that unless you have actual data which is `DateTime.MinValue` which you don't want to mix up with the "zero" value, you *just* specify `ConvertZeroDateTime=true` and detect if the result is `DateTime.MinValue`. You definitely *shouldn't* call `reader.GetDateTime()`, then convert the result to a string, and then back to a `DateTime` - you should avoid string conversions as far as you can, as they can mess things up for you pretty easily.

It's not really clear what string value you want for these "zero" values, but you should be able to special-case them with `DateTime.MinValue` fairly easily. Personally I'd actually try to keep the data in its "native" form as much as possible rather than converting everything to strings, but that's a different battle.