# Unable to scaffold “datetime” type columns from MySQL in .net core 3.1

Tags: mysql, datetime, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

A similar issue has been posted in the past about [scaffolding in .net core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449661/unable-to-scaffold-date-type-columns-from-mysql-in-net-core-2) but that was on a `date` column and no solution has been posted to date.

There's no specific table as any table containing a `datetime` column type throws the following error from the console:

```
Could not find type mapping for column 'database.table.columnname' with data type 'datetime'. Skipping column.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982137/unable-to-convert-mysql-datetime-to-system-datetime-with-0000-00-00-000000-val#15982230) to a question about reading `datetime` values and a MySQL quirk with `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values made me wonder if changing the connection string format would help. So I added the `ConvertZeroDateTime=true` to the connection string in the scaffold command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=notherealpassword;database=sodb;ConvertZeroDateTime=true;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Model -f
```

I still have the same error, does anyone have any suggestions? I have 380+ tables in this database so an automated solution would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and now I solved it.

I can't be assured if my solution works to your case but I think this solution would work to your case.

1. Remove all packages related to Entity Framework.
2. Install the following packages the version is 5.0.4

[image]

3. Open Package Manager Console window. Now we will install Pomelo packages it depends on .Net standard.
4. Enter the command “Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -Version 5.0.0-alpha.2”
5. Enter the command "Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.NetTopologySuite -Version 5.0.0-alpha.2"

The commands try to install the following packages.

[image]

6. Now Enter to Package Manager Console window the following command.
   Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=notherealpassword;database=sodb; **"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql"** -OutputDir Models -f
7. The result of command is as below.
   [image]

I hope this post helps you.

Comment: This is by far the closest I've seen to getting this to work properly! Thank you. Can you please add to your answer that the Pomelo packages rely on .NETStandard?

Comment: Thank you. I added your advice to my post.
Modified content is as below.
3. Open Package Manager Console window. Now we will install Pomelo packages it depends on .Net standard.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I'd almost given up on this project!

Comment: to work for me I had to insert the package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational, thx anyways !

Answer (score 1):

I was scaffolding off mySql 5.7 in .net core 2.2 using pomelo no problem until i tried upgrading to 3.1

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6">
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.21" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.19" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
```

This combination worked for me calling

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext [ConnectionStringHere] MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir [NameHere] -Project "[NameHere]" -Force
```

With the below packages, scaffolding just skips datetime completely (also bytes are converted to bools)

So to workaround. I used my source control to keep the old datetime classes and just manually updated the bools. You could try downgrading to older versions to see if helps.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.11"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.11">
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.23" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.19" />
<PackageReference Include="NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6" Version="6.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved a fix for this today with the following Nugets: -
[image: EFCore / Net 5.0 / MySql]

And then in Package Manager Console of Visual Studio: -

**Scaffold-DbContext "server=MYSERVER;port=3306;database=MYDB;user=MYUSER;password=MYPW;" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -UseDatabaseNames -f**

*The "-UseDatabaseNames" and "-f" flags are not essential to the bare fix, but that's what I'm using*.

The crucial detail is that MySql.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.3 works where v5.0.0 does not.

Comment: It continued to work when I bravely updated Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design to v5.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I was getting datetime/timestamp erros like yours, I must had to use those packages to made to work
mysql.entityframeworkcore isnt necessary

[image]

And the command to export is

```sh
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Database=@dbname;Data Source=@ip:@port;User Id=@user;Password=@pass;Initial Catalog=@dbname;" pomelo.entityframeworkcore.mysql -o Models -f -c DBContext
```